# .js file does not work with asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

i have the following simple javascript function

```
function invokeMeMaster() {
    alert('I was invoked from page');
}
```

it works properly in the code but when i add it as an external js file noting happens.
i try to add js file and call this function in a button click as this

```
<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
    <script  type="text/javascript">   src = <%= ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/JScript1.js")%> </script>

</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">

   <asp:Button ID="btnMaster" runat="server" Text="Button"  OnClientClick="invokeMeMaster();"/>

</asp:Content>
```

what am i missing? the code does not work in this way?
rhanks

Comment: Read the generated source and you will be enlightened.

Answer (score 2):

`src` is an **attribute** of the `<script>` tag.

You're creating a Javascript variable and assigning it to invalid syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Your script tag isn't correctly formed. Try:

```
<script  type="text/javascript" src='<%= ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/JScript1.js")%>' ></script>
```

Comment: I have try this, but nothing happens? please help ?!

Comment: Is your JScript1.js file definitely at the following directory: *root*/Scripts/JScript1.js? All the spelling correct? I get tripped up all the time by one rogue character...

Answer (score 0):

Youcan try this:-

```
<script  type="text/javascript" src = <%= ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/JScript1.js")%>>    </script>
```

instead of

```
<script  type="text/javascript">   src = <%= ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/JScript1.js")%> </script>
```

`src` should be included in the `script` tag.

Answer (score 0):

The code should look like this:

```
<script  type="text/javascript" src='<%= ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/JScript1.js")%>'> </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you can do this... I personally would give the button control a class (CssClass property) and target that with JavaScript.

Using jQuery, I would do:

```
(function () {
    function invokeMeMaster() {
        alert('I was invoked from page');
    }

    $('.btnMaster').click(function() {
        invokeMeMaster();
    });
});
```

I honestly wouldn't even use the the asp:button control. It expects to have a post back... I mean, there isn't anything wrong with using it per-se, but my approach would be different.